# What are my options to rename a (huge) cache_form table which takes way to long?

Tags: caching

I inherited a website that has cache_form more than 33Gb.

I've followed the following steps:

```
CREATE TABLE new_cache_form LIKE cache_form;

RENAME TABLE cache_form TO cache_form_backup;
```

And in other session:

```
RENAME TABLE new_cache_form TO cache_form;
```

Query is taking long long time and site is not responding.

What could the solutions be?

Comment: Since it is a cache table, I'd assume you should be good to simply delete it. I've migrated some sites skipping on all the cache tables and sites are still performing fine. But maybe some people have other thoughts.

Comment: Don't delete it! I assume you meant 'truncate' or 'empty' it.

Answer (score 0):

"Waiting for table metadata lock" will happen with a TRUNCATE or a RENAME and once this query is slated to run all other requests behind it will be stalled. There is no way to tell if a query will have a metadata lock unless you attempt to run it. So if the query does indeed cause a metadata lock you'll want to kill that query and use DELETE FROM instead as this is a [DML](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-syntax-data-manipulation.html) statement where as TRUNCATE or RENAME are [DDL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-syntax-data-definition.html) statements.

I created a module that handles the above logic: [APDQC](https://www.drupal.org/project/apdqc)

If you want to investigate this you self [slides 104](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1Vaad5ToVU1lc7zWdN3qN3oFl4FBeeiHqteFyEeXurcs/edit#slide=id.g4959d0709_462) - 113 of my 2015 DIY Drupal 7 Performance talk is a good start. How to create a stored procedure in order to auto kill stalled queries: http://mysqlblog.fivefarmers.com/2012/08/28/identifying-and-killing-blocking-transactions-in-innodb/

Comment: Thank you very much for detailed response.
Commands in my question worked but took site down for 30 min. Now, Even though form_cache is small now but it still creates problems.

 I have reviewed your module, it is definitely a right choice.

We use HAPROXY with Five loadbalancing Ubuntu14.04 VMs and one  seperate Database server. All five VMs have Apache2, Drupal 7.26.
 
APDQC would need install on all five machines and configured. Do you think any risks are involved for production website. 

Right now we face table lock issue, cannot create or delete nodes. Frequent 504, 503 errors. plz.help.

Comment: @Monsoonpk You need to update to [Drupal 7.32 or higher](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal) OR apply [this patch](https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/SA-CORE-2014-005-D7.patch) to core due to the [SQL Injection SA](https://www.drupal.org/SA-CORE-2014-005). After that has been done https://www.drupal.org/project/drupalgeddon is a good tool to see how much damage was done. Updating core to 7.40 would be good as that contains big speed improvements. Finally get APDQC on each server, make sure mysqlnd is installed & then enable it. Go to the status report page and follow the directions given.

Comment: I have applied the patch since upgrade is not possible. I can successfully enable the module after installing mysqlnd. 
But when I add the lines below settings.php according to status report, on all five Servers. I get the following:

PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user &#039;soluser&#039;@&#039;localhost&#039; (using password: YES) in system_list() (line 136 of ncludes/module.inc).

PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user &#039;soluser&#039;@&#039;localhost&#039; (using password: YES) in db_merge() (line 2445 of //database/database.inc).

Comment: I have loads of these errors in dblog:
PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1205

Comment: @Monsoonpk You might need to grant the mysql user all the permissions as it reads from non drupal tables. Looks like I need to check for this inside of APDQC. Also see this issue: https://www.drupal.org/node/2605268#comment-10511940 as setting the transaction-isolation level, innodb_lock_wait_timeout, and wait_timeout settings for MySQL inside the settings.php might not always work.

Comment: Thank you for consistent help. 
I've this line in my.cnf:  innodb_lock_wait_timeout=120.

I granted all rights and permissions to the user and moved one step forward, I think. Here is a new error below.

PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1665 Cannot execute statement: impossible to write to binary log since BINLOG_FORMAT = STATEMENT and at least one table uses a storage engine limited to row-based logging. InnoDB is limited to row-logging when transaction isolation level is READ COMMITTED or READ UNCOMMITT............

Comment: @Monsoonpk `innodb_lock_wait_timeout=120`. You'll want this closer to 20 seconds. PHP usually times out after 30 seconds so 120 seconds means that you'll have some open transactions in the event of a database deadlock, which makes the problem worse. Thanks for letting me know about the binlog format issue. You should be able to use mixed instead of statement.

Comment: I have successfully enabled APDQC after setting binlog_format = mixed  on all five VMs. Now on modules settings page all the buttons are disabled, and I am not able perform operations. Besides, site is very slow. waiting for tips.. :)

Comment: Perhaps I should use command line ? What could be the commands or queries?

Comment: Buttons getting disabled would be caused by something else.

Comment: I've found that. I can get buttons enabled by putting site offline. Since I have to perform the operations on the live site by putting it offline for a while. Do you think it is safe to perform all three operations given on modules settings page?

Comment: It's safe to preform the operations on the `admin/config/development/performance/apdqc/operations` page as long as the site is offline. It will do some DDL statements on the cache tables.

Comment: I need your urgent help. I could enable the module apdqc but did not perform operation mentioned on apdqc configuration page since taking site offline was not possible. In the mean time xen ubuntu VM containing database server hanged and went offline. No SSH access to the VM. I can access xen server but can't restart VM. Any idea how can access the database backup in the VM through xen server command line?